# How to make make run the subtasks for periodic task with Celery?

Tags: python, celery

I would like to create *periodic* task which makes query to database, get's data from data provider, makes some API requests, formats documents and sends them using another API.

Result of the previous task should be chained to the next task. I've got from the documentation that I have to use **chain**, **group** and **chord** in order to organise chaining.

But, what else I've got from the documentation: don't run subtask from the task, because it might be the reason of deadlocks.

So, the question is: how to run subtasks inside the periodic task?

```
@app.task(name='envoy_emit_subscription', ignore_result=False)
def emit_subscriptions(frequency):
# resulting queryset is the source for other tasks
    return Subscription.objects.filter(definition__frequency=1).values_list('pk', flat=True)



@app.task(name='envoy_query_data_provider', ignore_result=False)
def query_data_provider(pk):
    # gets the key from the chain and returns received data
    return "data"


@app.task(name='envoy_format_subscription', ignore_result=False)
def format_subscription(data):
    # formats documents
    return "formatted text"


@app.task(name='envoy_send_subscription', ignore_result=False)
def send_subscription(text):
    return send_text_somehow(text)
```

Sorry for the noob question, but I'm a noob in Celery, indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe?

```
import time

while True:
    my_celery_chord()
    time.sleep(...)
```

Comment: What the reason to add sleep? It blocks the execution. And why do we need infinite loop?

Comment: This is the simplest solution I could think of. You will need some form of loop to retrigger the tasks. I think celery does provide for periodic tasks. Sleep just so that it doesn't retrigger too often. A better solution may be found [here](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html).

Comment: Sorry @tammo, but I think that you don't understand the question. I know how to use periodic tasks. The question was: what the right way of running subtasks from the periodic task?  Direct calling of delay or apply_async may be the reason of deadlock.

Comment: Entirely possible. You are doing it right with chaining tasks. This is where typically the problem lays. Calling a chain from a periodic task should be ok. After all, that is what periodic tasks are designed to do.